# AWS EC2 - Where I find how many EBS (in Gigabytes) I'll get for creating Instance when I use t3.medium instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS EC2, How much Storage I can use when I create an Instance of `t3.medium` ???

I tried to create an instance but I did not know how much storage I get to use ...

Can Anyone Help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8GB would be enough for you to launch an instance. 
Moreover if required you can increase your instance volume size without any reboot.

https://github.com/matesio/AWS-helper-scripts/blob/master/increase-ssd-ec2.sh